# Positive and negative numbers

Tags: python

```
def main():
i = int( input ("Enter an interger, the input ends if it is 0: "))
count_pos = 0
count_neg = 0
total = 0
if (i != 0):
    while (i != 0):
        if (i > 0):
            count_pos += 1
        elif (i < 0):
            count_neg += 1
        total += i
    i = int( input ("Enter an interger, the input ends if it is 0: "))
    count = count_pos + count_neg

print ("The number of positives is", count_pos)
print ("The number of negatives is", count_neg)
print ("The total is", total)
```

File "", line 16
    print ("The number of positives is", count_pos)
                                                  ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is quite trivial.

Comment: edited it there u go my try

Comment: Please fix the indentation. It's difficult to debug code that doesn't run, or worse, runs differently than it's supposed to.

Comment: @wqiejwqdjoiwqdwqewqewq: The code you posted isn't runnable. It'll crash with a `SyntaxError`. And I think a few lines of code aren't correctly indented - is `average = total / count` really  inside your `while (i != 0):` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See  let's take a list , say sample_list

```
sample_list = [1, 5, -9, 6, 7, -7, -2, -4, 2, 3]
```

Or

```
sample_list = []
while True:
    a = int(raw_input())
    if a==0: break
    else:sample_list.append(a)
```

Now, To get the length of list

```
sample_list_length = len(sample_list)
```

where len() is a inbuilt function which returns the length of any iterable object like strings,lists,etc.

```
positive_number = 0
negative_number = 0
for dummy_number in sample_list:
    if dummy_number>=0:
        positive_number+=1
    else:
        negative_number+=1

print "There are",positive_number,"positive numbers"
print "There are",negative_number,"negative numbers"
print "There are",sample_list_length,"total numbers"
```

Comment: But if you want the user to enter the number to the list then see the edit

Comment: Sorry for keep you waiting @wqiejwqdjoiwqdwqewqewq

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

First of all,

```
while (i != 0):
    if (i > 0):
        count_pos += 1
    elif (i < 0):
        count_neg += 1
    total += i
```

is an infinite loop. `i` never changes, so if `i!=0` is True the first time, then it'll always be True.

Next,

```
i = int( raw_input ("Enter an interger, the input ends if it is 0: "))
count = count_pos + count_neg
```

are completely unnecessary. Neither `i` not `count` is ever used in the following code.

---

The fixed code:

```
def main():
    count_pos = 0
    count_neg = 0
    while True:
        i = int( input ("Enter an interger, the input ends if it is 0: "))
        if i > 0:
            count_pos += 1
        elif i < 0:
            count_neg += 1
        else:
            break

    print ("The number of positives is", count_pos)
    print ("The number of negatives is", count_neg)
    print ("The total is", count_pos+count_neg)
```

Comment: And how would you create a program that can see if the comment is possitive or negative?

Comment: @wqiejwqdjoiwqdwqewqewq: What comment are you referring to?